# GeneXus16のSmartDevicePanelでPOPUP画面をフルスクリーンで起動したい。

Tags: android

GeneXus16 U11でAndroid版バーコードスキャナの開発しています。
起動元のSmartDevicePanelからPopupで別のSmartDevicePanelを呼び出しています。

```
呼出先_SDP.CallOptions.Type = CallType.Popup
呼出先_SDP.CallOptions.TargetSize = CallTargetSize.Large
呼出先_SDP.Call()
```

呼出先の画面が上下左右２～３dip分程度小さく表示されます。
最大化の状態で表示することは出来ないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

> 呼出先_SDP.CallOptions.TargetSize = CallTargetSize.Large

の部分を下記のようにサイズ指定にしてはどうでしょう。

```
呼出先_SDP.CallOptions.TargetWidth = !'100%'
呼出先_SDP.CallOptions.TargetHeight = !'100%'
```